# LeanFT and Selenium Compatibility?

Tags: selenium, architecture, frameworks, leanft

I would like to know if Selenium and LeanFT can play nicely together. I don't know if anyone has tried to do this yet, but I think if it can work, LeanFT can provide some supplementary benefits to the selenium framework.

As I understand it currently, the limitations of Selenium are:

- Selenium MUST open the initial browser to recognize it
- Selenium MUST open all popups to recognize them.
- Selenium WebDriver may become stale while waiting for non-Selenium procedures.

I have attempted the object flow UML for both HP's suggested model and my own idea of how this might work.

[image: HP Object Flow]

[image: Selenium and LeanFT Object Flow]

The Control flow would be something like:

1. @Before -> globalSetup (LeanFT init)
2. @BeforeClass -> testSetup (LeanFT init)
3. @BeforeClass -> getSeleniumDriver (Selenium)
4. @Test -> *some selenium procedures*
   /**** To prevent Selenium from dying. ****/
5. @Test -> new Thread -> run leanFTsnippet1()
6. @Test -> *resume selenium final steps..*
7. @After -> reporting, closing Webdriver

Here is some of my current code from an example Test Class.

```
@BeforeClass
public static void beforeLFTClass() throws Exception {
    globalSetup(CoreFunctionality.class);
}

@AfterClass
public static void afterLFTClass() throws Exception {
    globalTearDown();
}

@Test
public void runLeanFtThread() {
    // put selenium code here
             // ...
             // begin leanft part of test
    Thread leanftThread = new Thread( new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                test();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    leanftThread.start();
    try {
        leanftThread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public void test() throws Exception {

    //Starting Browser
    Browser browser = BrowserFactory.attach(new BrowserDescription.Builder().title(driver.getTitle()).build());
    Assert.assertEquals(browser.getTitle(), driver.getTitle());
}
```

Anyways, its a pretty interesting problem. Would really love to see what you guys think.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

They indeed play nicely together. I have been using them in my scripts and I like to utilize the powers of each tool. What I have done is create a LeanFT test template and add the Selenium libraries to it.

Here is a sample code:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using HP.LFT.SDK;
using HP.LFT.SDK.Web;
using Search_Regression_Test;
using TestAutomationReporting;
using UnifiedFramework;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Diagnostics;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using Selenium = OpenQA.Selenium;
namespace Search_Regression_Test
{
    [TestClass]
    public class LeanFtTest : UnitTestClassBase<LeanFtTest>
    {        
        static IBrowser browser;        
        static IWebDriver chromeDriver;

        [ClassInitialize]
        public static void ClassInitialize(TestContext context)
        {

            GlobalSetup(context);                        
            ChromeOptions CO = new ChromeOptions();
            CO.AddExtension(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\HP\LeanFT\Installations\Chrome\Agent.crx");
            chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver(CO);
            chromeDriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

            browser = BrowserFactory.Attach(new BrowserDescription
            {
                Type = BrowserType.Chrome
            });
```

.... and so on.

Answer (score 1):

The new Version of LeanFT (14) even brings some explicit Selenium-integration: You can select Selenium as your automation SDK in the project creation wizard, there is a Selenium-specific Object Identification Center, and some additional locators and utilities. Full story here: [LeanFT for Selenium](http://leanft-help.saas.hpe.com/en/14.00/HelpCenter/Content/HowTo/Sel_LeanFT4SelT.htm).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure why this question doesn't have an accepted answer yet, but I'm going to take a stab at answering this with a sample that highlights once more that **LeanFT and Selenium are playing nicely together**

It's written in Java. Probably it can be optimized a bit, but it should clearly show how you can achieve simultaneous interaction with the same browser.

*(The Java Project was created from LeanFT templates. UnitTestClassBase class comes from there. It basically initializes LeanFT and the reporter behind the scenes. To get around it if you don't want to use it you'd have to call `SDK.init()`, `Reporter.init()`, `Reporter.generateReport()` and `SDK.cleanup()` as needed - [check the docs for details](https://leanft-help.saas.hpe.com/en/14.01/HelpCenter/Content/HowTo/CustomFrameworks.htm))*

The AUT used is advantage shopping: http://advantageonlineshopping.com/

```
package com.demo;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import com.hpe.leanft.selenium.By;
import com.hp.lft.report.Reporter;
import com.hp.lft.report.Status;
import com.hp.lft.sdk.web.*;
import com.hp.lft.verifications.Verify;


public class SeleniumTest extends UnitTestClassBase {
    private ChromeDriver chromeDriver;
    private Browser browser;
    public SeleniumTest() {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",this.getClass().getResource("/chromedriver.exe").getPath());

    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
        instance = new SeleniumTest();
        globalSetup(SeleniumTest.class);
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception {
        globalTearDown();
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        // SELENIUM: Construct and launch the browser with LeanFT agent
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        File paths = new File("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\HP\\LeanFT\\Installations\\Chrome\\Agent.crx");
        options.addExtensions(paths);

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);

        chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);

    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        // LEANFT: close the browser opened by selenium
        browser.close();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {

        // SELENIUM: Go to the Advantage shopping website and maximize it
        chromeDriver.get("http://156.152.164.67:8080/#/");
        chromeDriver.manage().window().maximize();

        // LEANFT: Attach to the browser
        browser = BrowserFactory.attach(new BrowserDescription.Builder()
                .type(BrowserType.CHROME).openTitle(" Advantage Shopping")
                .build());


        // LEANFT: Click on tablets button
        browser.describe(WebElement.class, new WebElementDescription.Builder()
                .className("categoryCell").tagName("DIV").innerText("TABLETS Shop Now ").build()).click();

        // SELENIUM: Expand the display section after it was seen
        (new WebDriverWait(chromeDriver, 10))
          .until(new ExpectedCondition<org.openqa.selenium.WebElement>(){
            @Override
            public org.openqa.selenium.WebElement apply(org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver d) {
                return d.findElement(By.cssSelector("h4#accordionAttrib0"));
            }}).click();


        // LEANFT: select the preferred display size, click the preferred tablet and add the tablet to the cart
        browser.describe(CheckBox.class, new CheckBoxDescription.Builder()
                .type("checkbox").role("").accessibilityName("").tagName("INPUT").name("").index(1).build()).set(true);

        browser.describe(Image.class, new ImageDescription.Builder()
                .alt("").type(com.hp.lft.sdk.web.ImageType.NORMAL).tagName("IMG").index(1).build()).click();

        browser.describe(Button.class, new ButtonDescription.Builder()
                .buttonType("submit").tagName("BUTTON").name("ADD TO CART").build()).click();

        // SELENIUM: go to cart
        chromeDriver.get("http://156.152.164.67:8080/#/shoppingCart");

        // LEANFT: checkout
        browser.describe(Button.class, new ButtonDescription.Builder()
                .buttonType("submit").tagName("BUTTON").name("CHECKOUT ($1,009.00)").build()).click();

        // SELENIUM: Register as a new user after the button was seen
        (new WebDriverWait(chromeDriver, 10))
          .until(new ExpectedCondition<org.openqa.selenium.WebElement>(){
            @Override
            public org.openqa.selenium.WebElement apply(org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver d) {
                return d.findElement(By.xpath("//DIV[@id=\"newClient\"]/DIV[1]/SEC-FORM[1]/SEC-SENDER[1]/BUTTON[@role=\"button\"][1]"));
            }}).click();


        // LEANFT: fill in the user name and email
        String username = "U" + Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis(); // unique name each time
        browser.describe(EditField.class, new EditFieldDescription.Builder()
                .type("text").tagName("INPUT").name("userName").build()).setValue(username); 

        browser.describe(EditField.class, new EditFieldDescription.Builder()
                .type("text").tagName("INPUT").name("userEmail").build()).setValue("myuser_email@emailsite.org");

        // SELENIUM: Set password and confirm password
        chromeDriver.findElementByXPath("//SEC-VIEW/DIV[normalize-space()=\"*Password\"]/INPUT[1]").sendKeys("Password1");
        chromeDriver.findElementByXPath("//SEC-VIEW/DIV[normalize-space()=\"*Confirm password\"]/INPUT[1]").sendKeys("Password1");

        // LEANFT: check the 'I agree' checkbox and register, then click on next shipping details.
        browser.describe(CheckBox.class, new CheckBoxDescription.Builder()
                .type("checkbox").tagName("INPUT").name("registrationAgreement").build()).set(true);

        browser.describe(Button.class, new ButtonDescription.Builder()
                .buttonType("button").tagName("BUTTON").name("REGISTER").build()).click();

        browser.describe(Button.class, new ButtonDescription.Builder()
                .buttonType("submit").tagName("BUTTON").name("NEXT").build()).click();

        // SELENIUM: confirm the user name and pass
        chromeDriver.findElementByXPath("//DIV[@id=\"paymentMethod\"]/DIV/DIV/SEC-FORM/SEC-VIEW/DIV[normalize-space()=\"*SafePay username\"]/INPUT[1]").sendKeys(username);
        chromeDriver.findElementByXPath("//DIV[@id=\"paymentMethod\"]/DIV/DIV/SEC-FORM/SEC-VIEW/DIV[normalize-space()=\"*SafePay password\"]/INPUT[1]").sendKeys("Password1");

        // LEANFT: click "Pay now" and confirm payment was done
        browser.describe(Button.class, new ButtonDescription.Builder()
                .buttonType("button").role("button").accessibilityName("").tagName("BUTTON").name("PAY NOW").index(0).build()).click();
        Verify.isTrue(
                browser.describe(WebElement.class, new WebElementDescription.Builder()
                        .tagName("SPAN").innerText("Thank you for buying with Advantage").build())
                            .exists());
    }
}
```